# CS32F103C8T6 blue-pill clone - cannot flash from AC6 SystemWorkbench

Tags: macos, stm32, bluepill

I am trying to flash a blue-pill clone with a CS32F103C8T6 chip using the AC6 SystemWorkBench and a ST-LINK v2 device. It is a project built from STM32CubeMX - I am using a MacOS Mojave machine. Here is the output when trying to flash the device.

```
Info : The selected transport took over low-level target control. The results might differ compared to plain JTAG/SWD
adapter speed: 8000 kHz
adapter_nsrst_delay: 100
Info : clock speed 8000 kHz
Info : STLINK v2 JTAG v31 API v2 SWIM v7 VID 0x0483 PID 0x3748
Info : using stlink api v2
Info : Target voltage: 3.162004
Info : Unable to match requested speed 8000 kHz, using 4000 kHz
Info : Stlink adapter speed set to 4000 kHz
Warn : UNEXPECTED idcode: 0x2ba01477
Error: expected 1 of 1: 0x1ba01477
in procedure 'program' 
in procedure 'init' called at file "embedded:startup.tcl", line 495
in procedure 'ocd_bouncer'
** OpenOCD init failed **
shutdown command invoked
```

I have googled and found some similar posts about it, but have no luck solving it.

Does anyone have an idea ?

mvh
Ole K Hornnes

Comment: Did you try flashing it with serial ?

Comment: With STM32CubeIDE, I often had similar issues. You can try to use STLink GDB server instead of OpenOCD (if it is possible on this IDE).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the OpenOCD config file, you need to add:

```
set CPUTAPID 0x2ba01477
```

I've never used AC6 SystemWorkbench and I don't now how you configure the board and the debug adapter in it. So I can't really tell where to look for the config file.

OpenOCD comes with an entire directory of board configurations, usually in a directory *OpenOCD* / *scripts* / *board*. It contains a script called `stm32f103c8_blue_pill.cfg`, which might be used in your case. Start there...

Comment: It was a bit hard to find this file, but when found this issue become solved. I found the file at: 
```
/Applications/Ac6/SystemWorkbench.app/Contents/Eclipse/plugins/fr.ac6.mcu.debug_2.5.0.201904120827/resources/openocd/st_scripts/target/stm32f1x.cfg
```

Answer (score 8):

**set CPUTAPID 0x2ba01477** ; Will work for the clone but not for the genuine STM32…

Instead use: **set CPUTAPID 0**

The zero tells OpenOCD to ignore the id number, so any MCU will then work…

Information Source: [OpenOCD TAPs](http://openocd.org/doc/html/TAP-Declaration.html#TAP-Declaration-Commands)

Answer (score 2):

C:\Ac6\SystemWorkbench\plugins\fr.ac6.mcu.debug_2.5.0.201904120827\resources\openocd\st_scripts\target\stm32f1x.cfg

add this line before first if statement

set CPUTAPID 0

it solves all openocd stlink id errors

Answer (score 0):

I'm running macOS on M1 and this was a bit of a pain but...

For anyone running this by invoking the `openocd` command manually like `openocd -f ...`, add a `-d` flag and run it like `openocd -d -f ...`. Search the output for `stm32f1x.cfg`. For example for me I found it at:

```
Debug: 26 1 command.c:155 script_debug(): command - ocd_find target/stm32f1x.cfg
Debug: 27 1 configuration.c:88 find_file(): found /usr/local/bin/../share/openocd/scripts/target/stm32f1x.cfg
```

So I can add `set CPUTAPID 0x2ba01477`, or even better per Johan's answer - `set CPUTAPID 0` to the top of the file at that file, specifically `/usr/local/bin/../share/openocd/scripts/target/stm32f1x.cfg`. I needed to use sudo to edit this file. Hope this generalizes the solution here.